# Method setInitParameter servletContext

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6

In "Head First servlet and jsp" there is writtern:

> You cannot set application and Servlet init parameters, they are set
>   in the DD

What is the use of [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setInitParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method then? 
Maybe it's a new feature and the book written in 2004 did not contemplate such a method?
Thanks in advance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the javadoc, it states [`@since` Servlet 3.0.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setInitParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

The Servlet 3.0 specification was released [much later than 2004.](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315)

You are correct in your assumption.

Comment: Thanks! does it change the dd automatically too?

Comment: @IndeedItIs The deployment descriptor is a static document. It doesn't change. When you call the method, the state of the application (or rather the `ServletContext`) changes.